# Maltego Local Transform: ParseError at [row,col];[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: python, csv

Im running a simple maltego transform taken from its website https://docs.maltego.com/support/solutions/articles/15000017605-local-transforms-example-#adding-the-transform-to-maltego-0-6 to get a person's name by searching their phone number.

My code looks like this.

```
 @staticmethod
    def get_names(search_phone):
        matching_names = []
        with open("phone_to_names.csv") as f:
            for ln in f.readlines():
                phone, name, age = ln.split(",", 2)
                if phone.strip() == search_phone.strip():
                    matching_names.append(name.strip())
        return matching_names


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(NameFromCSV.get_names("1-541-754-3010"))
```

And my csv looks like this

```
1-541-754-3010, John Smith, 23
1-541-800-6987, Jane Doe, 24
1-336-854-1155, Alex Walker, 25
```

When i run my transform on maltego i get **ParseError at [row,col];[1,1] Message: Content is not allowd in prolog**:

[image: Screenshot]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://githubhot.com/repo/paterva/maltego-trx/issues/9) by totakura

> What's happening here is that Maltego expects XML to be written to standard transforms by your local transforms. If for some reason you python script writes anything else to the standard output (e.g printing a stack trace upon an exception, logging, or simply print()'ing) Maltego throws this error.

I think if you comment the print line `print(NameFromCSV.get_names("1-541-754-3010"))` will fix this error